# Everytime same settings file by every application

Tags: c#, file, settings

I am programming a c# Program. The Settings are stored normal, with the settings which i can create in the properties. So the settings file is stored in the `Appdata\local`
But when I rename my application or do it in another directory, it creates a new folder and a new settings file. But i don't won't that so, i want, that it takes everytime the same settings file, whereever the program is stored.

I also tried with `settings.upgrade()`, but that works only by new versions.

The code is:

```
BlackJack.Properties.Settings.Default["KID"] = verschluesseln(s.getKontostand());
BlackJack.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If I forgot to say something, just ask.

Comment: Can you add some sample code?

Comment: Please, edit your question so every one can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a static configuration for your program, then you should use App.config file in your project.

Check this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), you can see how it is used. ConfigurationManager class is responsible for getting the values from your App.config file.

Comment: No sorry, it isn't that. I just want to use the normal settings function, which i can edit in the properties. Do you know which one i mean?

Comment: @user3790689 yes I understood which one you mean. But settings files are not designed the way you want. That's why I suggested app.config files.